# Flex RemoteObject need syntax for that

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am new in FLEX. I want the syntax for RemotObject.
Please give me the syntax of that.
I am using FLEX 3.0 and backend is .NET

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this and following is the syntax for that.

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="roTestQuestion" destination="GenericDestination"  
    source="FlexDataLayer.BusinessLogic.TestQuestionBLL" showBusyCursor="true" fault="    {onFault(event);}">
    <mx:method name="GetList" result="{roTestQuestion_GetList(event);}"   />
    <mx:method name="GetAnswerList" result="{roTestQuestion_GetAnswerList(event);}"   />
    <mx:method name="Insert" result="{roTestQuestion_Insert(event);}"  />
    <mx:method name="Update" result="{roTestQuestion_Update(event);}"  />
    <mx:method name="Delete" result="{roTestQuestion_Delete(event);}"  />
    <mx:method name="GetListByCategoryID" result="{roTestQuestion_GetListByCategoryID(event);}" />
</mx:RemoteObject>
```

source is you .NET class and u need to create a method that i have write in  fault and result.

for Fault

```
private function onFault(e:FaultEvent):void
{
Alert.show(e.fault.message.toString(),parentApplication.alertTitle);    
}
```

for Result

```
private function roTestQuestion_Delete(e:ResultEvent):void
        {
            if (e.result!= null)
            {
                if(cbCat.selectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    roTestQuestion.GetList();
                }
                else
                {
                    roTestQuestion.GetListByCategoryID(selIndex);
                }
                //roTestQuestion.GetList();
                //Application.application._mdlExamSelection.Init();
            }
        }
```

here i have give the method to call the method from remoteobject.

```
roTestQuestion.GetList();
```

You are beginner so i am advising you to go through the following link because in future u need to use the ActionScript and this link will going to be very useful to you...

Please visit this [Link](http://www.dlgsoftware.com/primers/Primer_on_Flex3_Component_Lifecycle.htm)

Comment: Thanks Sagar Rawal,
I will try this and inform you if i getting any problem.

Comment: no problem. I am sure that you will not going to phase any problem.